# Is it possible to chain Hall sensors?

Tags: hall-effect

I'm working on a hobby project that is to add sensors to a wooden chess board in order to detect if a piece is on a given square.

I'm quite beginner at electronics, only experienced in programming, not aware of terminology.

I've come across a few ideas, from reed switches to Hall sensors. In terms of sensors, I'd prefer Hall sensors (SS49E).

The next problem is how to read data.  I've seen a solution that uses a cd4067 to implement multiplexing. I'd need 4 of these.

Is there a solution that does some kind of chaining? An ideal solution would be to have a module with a Hall sensor belonged to each square and chain them together, read them similar to dealing with shift registers. Something like implementing a 1-bit shift register with the sensor on it. Sorry if this is stupid idea.

The goal is to minimise wiring and make the hardware simple.

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: Can you use a Hall switch such as the [A3144](https://www.surplustronics.co.nz/product/LA0350/info-738.pdf?1434514932) instead? If so then you could multiplex them in an 8x8 matrix.

Comment: My recommendation: Just do the wiring. 1-bit groups are inefficient since you'll need to buy a lot more chips. You can make modules of 4x4 squares each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "1-wire" bus protocol would suit your requirements. Do a search and see if there's a "1-wire Hall sensor". These can then be read directly by your microcontroller without any shift-registers.

1-wire devices are pre-programmed with unique addresses. An interesting little problem for you would be the registering the addresses of each sensor at each square. I suggest that you have a learning mode where you move a piece sequentially around the board, row by row, while recording which sensor is at which grid reference.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however I wasn't able to find hardware for this. I'll go with the mux way.